# Twilio Javascript Client New Leg Call SID

Tags: twilio

I've followed the tutorial here https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/client/javascript which will make an outbound call.

How would I go about collecting the Call SID of the outbound leg?  I can get the parent Call SID but not the outbound connection.

I would like this id so I can manipulate the live call.

Answer (score 0):

Using Twilio Client there are two parts , 
(1) Incoming API call into Twilio App 
(2) Outbound Dial , as a result of TwiML that does a `<Dial>` on the number entered on the Twilio Client UI . This is done by the [TwiML Application](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/dev-tools/twiml-apps) set for your Twilio Client

For getting Child SID , which would be the call sid of the outbound leg , your Voice URL setup for the [TwiML Application](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/dev-tools/twiml-apps) for your Twilio Client , should capture the call SID after doing the  .